# recover files after formatting and partitioning disk that originally had windows into kali linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, dual-boot

1. I had windows Os on a 160GB disk . so i created a bootable usb for kali linux to install  side by side with windows.  so during installation i selected partition method .( guided partitioning - use entire disk). then i selected All files in one partition (recommended for new users).  so the installation process began . then i shutdown the pc because i thought i made a mistake.
               2. so then i loaded the installation again this time choosing manual partioning method and the whole disk was shown as free space. i created a logical partition of 50 Gb plus swap space, and the rest was free space. i proceeded with installing kali linux on the 50GB partition.    thats when i decided to use the testdisk utility but i realy dont know what happened ?

using `testdisk` under advanced with disk partition marked x Extended shows

```
Boot sector
Status: Bad

Backup boot sector
Status: Bad

Sectors are not identical.
```

A valid NTFS Boot sector must be present in order to access
any data; even if the partition is not bootable.

Comment: "_I selected All files in one partition (recommended for new users)..._" If you are a new user, please don't use Kali. It's not a distribution intended for new users. Really.

Comment: Read our FAQ. If you have got a closed question, it is not nice opening another one with the same question.

Answer (score 4):

> i realy dont know what happened ?

You asked the installer to partition the entire disk, which it did, then you re-partitioned it yourself and installed Kali. Your Windows installation is gone.

As you’ve found out, TestDisk won’t be able to help. You might be able to recover some data using [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (with a separate drive to hold the recovered data), but at this point you should consider your data gone (or restore it from backups if you have any).

Comment: alright i just have to move on